# Touchpad Insensitive

Tags: touchpad

I have just purchased a Samsung RF511 and as always I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on it straight away.

Everything works out of the box fine except the Touchpad. I have to press quite hard on the touch pad for it to move and it's generally laggy and sloppy.

The touch pad is recognized as it should be "Elantech Touchpad"

Answer (score 4):

You can try playing with touchpad paremeters via `synclient`. Just enter `synclient` in a terminal and see what possible parameters there are. Try changing FingerLow and FingerHigh values by typing `synclient FingerHigh=7` etc.

Comment: Changing the synclient FingerHigh and FingerLow values does make it more responsive. But it still is very sluggish and inaccurate.

Comment: Keep experimenting with those parameters. Research about what they are. You may need to do some fine tuning. Samsung notebooks typically have low quality touchpads though.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
xinput
```

command. To identify Your touchpad write:

```
xinput list
```

and see which id belongs to Your touchpad. Then write:

```
xinput watch-props YourDeviceID
```

where YourDeviceID is Your touchpad's id. See what properties You can change. Maybe there is something like press force or similar?